# jQuery insertAfter with movement animation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, insertafter

How would I modify this code to show the animated movement (item moving from current location to the new location)?

http://jsfiddle.net/jT8Tt/25/

```
var order = [2, 3, 1, 5, 4];

for (var i = 1; i < order.length; i++) {
    $('li[data-number="' + order[i] + '"]').insertAfter($('li[data-number="' + order[i - 1] + '"]'));
}​
```

Comment: element.animate({ position }, function () { this.insertAfter etc });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This plugin](http://razorjack.net/quicksand/) does not answer directly to your question, but addresses and resolves the same problem.

Comment: Ooo awesome, I'll look into that plugin. Though the website seems to be down atm...